# How to improve the speed of a Laravel page that that queries for a large amount of data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

It takes to long for the server to respond to the query.  Part of the problem is running the data through a Laravel API Resource to restrict what data is delivered.

I am already using eager loading to improve the speed of the query and have used explain to ensure that it is efficient.  The database is well indexed and running Aurora DB from AWS.

I have tried using Redis for caching but the possible permutations of filtering, sorting and paginating the data make it seem impractical.  I wasn't able to get good results with this as warming the cache for all variations isn't possible. And because the user preferences for sorting and filtering are stored locally in the browser there isn't a simple default state to warm the cache for either.

Comment: I'd look at the output of `EXPLAIN` for the queries and ensure your database indexes are sensible, as a start.

Comment: How long is too long? Is this API returning a lot of data? Can you introduce paging to limit the amount of data being returned?

Comment: @ceejayoz, the poster addressed both of these suggestions already.

Comment: Is it 1 query / call or more. Consider using graphql for combining rest calls. Or even improve performance further by using not rest but websockets for your connection.

Comment: First of all you must determine at which point of your application is the bottleneck, so you can tackle it.
How does long your application takes to respond? How long does it take at bottleneck point? You can use XDebug to determine which operation is taking too long and try to optimize or change approach at this point.